# K-means fails with R in PowerBI NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)

Tags: r, k-means, powerbi

I'm using the Iris data set and trying to create an R Script Visual with color coded clustering based on k-means clustering. The script works fine in R-Studio, but fails in PowerBI Desktop.

Here is what I did:

- Import the Iris data set as a csv file.
- Create a new R Script Visual
- Select the feature columns (1-4. Excluded the 5th column that has the label)
- Use the code to create k-means clusters and plot with color

**Sample Data**

```
5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, Iris-setosa
4.9, 3,   1.4, 0.2, Iris-setosa
4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2, Iris-setosa
4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2, Iris-setosa
5,   3.6, 1.4, 0.2, Iris-setosa
5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4, Iris-setosa
4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3, Iris-setosa
5,   3.4, 1.5, 0.2, Iris-setosa
4.4, 2.9, 1.4, 0.2, Iris-setosa
...
7,   3.2, 4.7, 1.4, Iris-versicolor
6.4, 3.2, 4.5, 1.5, Iris-versicolor
6.9, 3.1, 4.9, 1.5, Iris-versicolor
5.5, 2.3, 4,   1.3, Iris-versicolor
6.5, 2.8, 4.6, 1.5, Iris-versicolor
...
6.7, 3.3, 5.7, 2.1, Iris-virginica
7.2, 3.2, 6,   1.8, Iris-virginica
6.2, 2.8, 4.8, 1.8, Iris-virginica
6.1, 3,   4.9, 1.8, Iris-virginica
6.4, 2.8, 5.6, 2.1, Iris-virginica
....
```

**Code**

```
# Create dataframe
# dataset <- data.frame(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4)
# Remove duplicated rows
# dataset <- unique(dataset)

 dataset <- scale(dataset)
 results <- kmeans(dataset, 3)
 plot(dataset[,3:4],  col = results$cluster)
```

**Error:**

```
Error Message:

R script error.
Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
Calls: kmeans -> do_one
Execution halted


Stack Trace:



Invocation Stack Trace:



Error details
R script error.
Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
Calls: kmeans -> do_one
Execution halted


Stack trace
Microsoft.PowerBI.ExploreServiceCommon.ScriptHandlerException: R script error.
Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
Calls: kmeans -> do_one
Execution halted
 ---> Microsoft.PowerBI.Radio.RScriptRuntimeException: R script error.
Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
Calls: kmeans -> do_one
Execution halted

   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Radio.RScriptWrapper.RunScript(String originalScript, Int32 timeoutMs)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.R.RScriptHandler.GenerateVisual(String script, String inputVariableName, IDataReader dataReader, Nullable`1 viewportWidthPx, Nullable`1 viewportHeightPx)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.R.RScriptHandler.GenerateVisual(String script, String inputVariableName, IDataReader dataReader, Nullable`1 viewportWidthPx, Nullable`1 viewportHeightPx)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.ExploreServiceCommon.ScriptVisualCommandFlow.RunInternal(Stream dataShapeResultStream, QueryBindingDescriptor& bindingDescriptor)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.ExploreServiceCommon.ScriptVisualCommandFlow.Run(Stream dataShapeResultStream, QueryBindingDescriptor& bindingDescriptor)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.ExploreHost.SemanticQuery.ExecuteSemanticQueryFlow.TransformDataShapeResult(QueryCommand transformCommand, String dataShapeId, SemanticQueryDataShapeCommand command, Stream dataShapeResultStream, QueryBindingDescriptor& bindingDescriptor)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.ExploreHost.SemanticQuery.ExecuteSemanticQueryFlow.ProcessAndWriteDataQuery(IQueryResultDataWriter queryResultDataWriter, DataShapeGenerationContext dsqGenContext, DataQuery query, ServiceErrorStatusCode& serviceErrorStatusCode)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.ExploreHost.SemanticQuery.ExecuteSemanticQueryFlow.ProcessAndWriteSemanticQueryCommands(IQueryResultsWriter queryResultsWriter, ExecuteSemanticQueryRequest request, IConceptualSchema conceptualSchema)

Activity ID
7608d0ca-3ae2-2f75-4cf6-13c4557d903b

Time
Tue Jun 28 2016 10:46:26 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time)

Version
2.34.4372.501 (PBIDesktop)
```

**Note**

If I filter the data on Column 5, the label, then k-means works. In fact I can filter for each label. I only get the error on the full, unfiltered dataset

This is the error when unfiltered
[image]

This is working with filtered
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the data set had an empty row as the very last row. It didn't show up n the option to filter with a bar chart, however, it did show up when I used a slicer.

**Option for Missing**
[image]

**Works with Data**
[image]

**The Fix**

All I had to do was remove the empty row and it worked as expected